# M2E lifecycle mapping - execute plugin only on eclipse run?

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

I'm using a maven plugin to generate some project resources at build time.  It executes in the process-resources phase.  I am currently instructing eclipse to ignore the plugin when it auto-builds, because I don't want every save to generate the resources.  However, I do want to generate the resources before allowing the project to run.

I tried changing the action associated with my plugin to execute, but this doesn't seem to actually cause eclipse to execute it either.  I've tried with runOnIncremental set to both false and true, or not present entirely.

```
        <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>my-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[0.0.1-SNAPSHOT,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>my-goal</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <execute>
                                      <runOnIncremental>false</runOnIncremental>
                                    </execute>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
```

Is there a way to get eclipse to generate my resources automatically when I run?

Comment: did you try <runOnConfiguration> ? the real answer is that you need to modify your plugin to play [nicely with m2e](http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_compatible_maven_plugins) and avoid the whole lifecycle-mapping but maybe you'll be lucky with runOnConfiguration. I don't know how to actually run a maven goal every time you launch an app

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  runOnConfiguration doesn't seem to help either, and I'm kind of confused about how this plugin mapping even works.  It seems like there is no way to make my plugin execute automatically ever, regardless of what I put in here.  It executes whenever I manually do a maven build or install, but eclipse's auto build doesn't trigger it.  I wonder if I need to configure m2e somehow.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by play nicely with m2e?  I know that if I make my plugin only run during one of the non-interesting phases, I won't need lifecycle mapping, but I need to generate resources before any of the code executes.

Comment: read the link i posted on my comment. basically, the plugins have to be m2e aware, which IMHO is too much to ask, but it is what it is

Comment: Ah, I didn't see the link highlighting.  Thanks, I'll take a look.